# Can I ignore Automapper properties on a one-off basis?

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I am using Automapper to map EF objects to DTOs; many of the objects are in many-to-many arrangements. For example:

```
committee (table) 1 =< m  committeemember (table)  m >= 1 person (table)
```

That might map to:

```
public class CommitteeViewModel
{
    public int idCommittee { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CommitteeMemberViewModel> CommitteeMembers { get; set; }
}

public class CommitteeMemberViewModel
{
    public int idCommittee { get; set; }
    public int idCommitteeMember { get; set; }
    public PersonViewModel Members { get; set; }
}
```

And there are Automapper maps for `<committee, CommitteeViewModel>`, `<committeemember, CommitteeMemberViewModel>`, and `<person, PersonViewModel>`.

All is well when I want to return a single committee and its members.

BUT, when I want a list of committees without members, is there a way to ask Automapper to ignore certain properties, just for that call? Sort of like:

```
var committeeList = Automapper.Mapper.Map
    <List<committee>, List<CommitteeViewModel>>(committees)
   .Ignore("CommitteeMembers");
```

Of course, I can create new DTOs that omit these properties and map to those, but since I essentially want everything *but* one property, I thought there might be a better way, like creating a different map -- but I'm not managing to find it.

Thanks,

g.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot specify exceptions to your mappings at "*map-time*". What you CAN do is specify conditions for member mappings like `ForMember(d => d.Items, opt => opt.Condition(s => s.Count > 4))`. Not sure if that helps your case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve desired result this way: create new mapping (i.e. overwrite existing one), map your source entities, and override mapping back:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<committee, CommitteeViewModel>()
      .ForMember(c => c.CommitteeMembers, o => o.Ignore());

var committeeList = Mapper
      .Map<List<committee>, List<CommitteeViewModel>>(committees);

Mapper.CreateMap<committee, CommitteeViewModel>();
```

But I think it's better to keep things consistent. If I do mapping from committee to CommitteeViewModel I expect it will produce same result each time. So, it's better to create new view model for 'light' version of mapping.

Comment: This would work, but I wouldn't recommend it as you'd be scattering mapper configuration all through your codebase. If it were me, I'd investigate @khellang's suggestion.

Comment: @Mightymuke as you can see, I don't recommend this either. Also condition on source will not help here

Comment: Thanks -- now I can stop hunting! And I agree -- multiple targets seems to be the best way to go.